# What is the c# SMO way to create an Azure ClusteredColumnStoreIndex for a P1 SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, smo

Using a SQL Azure P1 Premium, V12 in North Europe, I can do this:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci_Simple ON SimpleTable;
```

but not this: (using Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91)

```
var t = new Table(db, "SimpleTable");
// ... Add Columns
t.Create()
var index = new Index(t, "cci_" + t.Name)
{
     IndexType = IndexType.ClusteredColumnStoreIndex,
};
index.Create();
```

I get:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationExceptionCreate failed for Index 'cci_SimpleTable'. 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.Create()
at ...
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UnsupportedEngineTypeException
```

Either the object or one of its properties is not supported on the target engine type.

References;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg492153.aspx

http://www.nikoport.com/2014/12/12/azure-columnstore-1-the-initial-preview-offering/

Comment: I wonder if this is the issue:  `at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CheckTargetDatabaseEngineTypeNotCloud(DatabaseEngineType targetDatabaseEngineType, String exceptionMessage)`

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format("Create Clustered Columnstore Index CC_{0} on dbo.{0}", table.Name));
```

sqlInjection escaping etc